# How to run through a list and return some strings for each entry?

Tags: haskell

How can I run through a list and return something for each element?

Here's a small example:

```
stack = [("ax","bx"),("cx","dx")]

test :: [(String, String)] -> String
test [] = ""
test (x:xs) = do
    reverse (fst x)
    test xs
```

How can I make this?

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Can you give example output?  Example usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. If you want to reverse the first element of each tuple and return the results in a list:

```
stack = [("ax","bx"),("cx","dx")]

test :: [(String, String)] -> [String]
test [] = []
test (x:xs) = reverse (fst x) : test xs
```

If you want the result as a single string, try:

```
stack = [("ax","bx"),("cx","dx")]

test :: [(String, String)] -> String
test [] = ""
test (x:xs) = reverse (fst x) ++ test xs
```

To apply a function to each element of a list, you might also want to look at `map`.

Answer (score 3):

```
test = concatMap (reverse . fst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test :: [(String, String)] -> String
test = foldr (\x r -> reverse (fst x) ++ r) ""
```

?

Comment: People really love `foldr` for some reason.  You know that `foldr (\x r -> f x ++ r) [] = map f` right?

Comment: `foldr (\x r -> reverse (fst x) ++ r) "" [("12", "13"), ("324", "56")]` => "21423". `map (\x -> reverse (fst x)) [("12", "13"), ("324", "56")]` => ["21","423"]. `++` is not `:`

Comment: @hoha, there is also `concat`, and for that matter `concatMap`.

Comment: @dave4420, yes, but I'm a Haskell newbie so I didn't know about these functions. "if all you have is a lambda, everything looks like a fold" :)

Comment: @hoha: `concatMap` is a pretty standard collection operation: Ruby (`flat_map`, aliased as `collect_concat`), Scala (`flatMap`), .NET (`SelectMany`).